# Windows 10 won't allow to connect to open Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration

I am trying to connect to an open Wi-Fi network, but somehow Windows 10 does not allow it, and I get the following message:

`Can't connect to this network`

Sometimes I manage to connect (after many trials), but in that case it says `No internet`

I even formatted and reinstalled Windows 10, but nothing.

I can connect through my phone without any problem. I can also use other devices without any problem.

Is there a firewall or network security system that does not allow me to connect?

Comment: I have a spot far from most people where the wireless is open. No problem connecting with Windows 10 Pro. Try running TCP/IP Reset and DNS Flush:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer and test

Comment: Resetting winsock seems to fix this issue the majority of the time for me. Try opening command prompt as administrator and running `netsh winsock reset` YOu will then have to restart. This is a blanket solution that may work without diving into the more technical stuff

Comment: If you use a specific DNS provider such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1), try switching to Auto DNS lookup. One public WiFi spot I used now blocks that IP, and the network showed as connected, but without internet until the DNS setting wss changed.

Comment: Finally I could solve it by using a Wifi USB Adapter. But what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it just by using a USB WiFi Adapter. Is there a good explanation?

I guess it's related to the Wifi device driver, but I don't have any problem to connect to another open Wifi network.